# Create folder in google drive and upload file REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, project

I am working on project using reactjs ,In that I want to access user's google drive and create my own folder
and upload file in it , Creating folder is not done by user ,it should be done automatically in backend ,I just ask to user for accessing google drive....

I am trying use of google drive API in reactjs but creating folder and uploading I am not getting
Can anyone help me out in this?
Thank you.....

Comment: About `I am trying use of google drive API in reactjs but creating folder and uploading I am not getting`, I thought that in this case, when you provide your current script and the detailed information about `I am not getting`, it will help users think of your current issue and a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.